# Rails One-to-one Child Attribute Accessed as Self Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes, one-to-one

It's been a few year since I did any Rails development.  There used to be a way to access a child attribute, in a one-to-one relationship, as that model's attribute.

So for instance, if you had two models: `Person` and `Address`, and they had a 1:1 relationship, you could pull back `@person.zip_code`, instead of `@person.address.zip_code`.

This used to be easy to do when you could explicitly define the accessible attributes in the model.  It seems this is gone now in Rails 4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still available in Rails 4.
What you want is `delegate` method.

```
class Address
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person
  has_one :address
  delegate :zip_code, to: :address
end
```

Now you can do `@person.zip_code`.

Please read the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) to learn more about options such as `prefix` and `allow_nil`.

Comment: Perfect!!  Thank you.  That is so much easier.